# Angular nativeElement is Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF from HTML content in an Angular application.

Here's my parent component:

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- ... other HTML content ... -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" #pdfTable>
            <!-- Table content -->
        </table>
    </div>
    <app-pdf-explosion-insumos-proyecto [tableElement]="pdfTable"></app-pdf-explosion-insumos-proyecto>
</div>
```

**Parent Component TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// ... other imports ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-explosion-insumos-concepto',
  templateUrl: './explosion-insumos-concepto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./explosion-insumos-concepto.component.css']
})
export class ExplosionInsumosConceptoComponent implements OnInit {
  // ... other properties ...

  @ViewChild('pdfTable', { static: false }) pdfTable: ElementRef;

  // ... constructor and ngOnInit ...
}
```

And here's my child component:

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button mat-min-fab class="btn btn-error btn-round btn-fab float-right" (click)="downloadPDF()">
    <i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i>
</button>
```

**Child Component TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import 'moment/locale/es'; 
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-explosion-insumos-proyecto',
  templateUrl: './pdf-explosion-insumos-proyecto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-explosion-insumos-proyecto.component.css']
})

export class PdfExplosionInsumosProyectoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableElement: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  downloadPDF() {
    if (this.tableElement) {
      html2canvas(this.tableElement.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const doc = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'landscape',
          unit: 'px',
          format: [canvas.width, canvas.height]
        });
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        doc.save('tabla-explosion-insumos.pdf');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I'm passing the HTML table from the parent component to the child component, and I can successfully obtain the HTML code of the parent in the child. However, when I try to perform operations that require **`nativeElement`**, it appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@Input() tableElement: ElementRef;` to `@Input() tableElement: HTMLTableElement;`

`#pdfTable` is already the nativeElement